# Webscraping grades login issue with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write code that will get a screenshot of my grades from my college's site and send them to me by email. I've had some trouble when I'm logging in, as soon as I submit the form with my username and password I find myself in a '..hangup.php3' page, that redirects me to the log-in page.

I need to find a way to get somehow past this page, would appreciate any help or ideas!

That's the college's URL, it's in Hebrew: https://portal.afeka.ac.il/desktop

```
import smtplib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


service = Service(r"C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

    def login():
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://portal.afeka.ac.il/desktop")
        time.sleep(5)
        username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
        password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
        username.send_keys("username")
        time.sleep(5)
        password.send_keys("password")
        time.sleep(5)
        password.submit()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: May I assume that "username" and "password" are not actually valid creds? It will be quite hard to reproduce your issue without valid credentials, which I'm guessing you cannot provide?